# How to get a [0-100] average from [-1,1] quotient

Tags: average, means

Suppose I have several records of good ($x$) and bad ($y$).

Each good represents one and each bad represents one too.

The sample size is calculated by $n = x+y$.

In order to calculate the quotient of good and bad I apply this formula:

$(x-y)/n$ that return a value in $[-1, 1]$.

How would I convert this value to a average rate from zero to hundred supposing that zero is the most close to $-1$ and hundred the most close to $1$?

Comment: How about $50 (x-y) / n + 50$?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Elvorfirilmathredia submit a answer so I can accept.